# Google Earth Engine video export error (a.element.map is not a function)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to export a time-lapse here but got a weird error:

```
Error Creating or Submitting Task
a.element.map is not a function
```

I want to keep the visParams on my exported video by visualize() which I'm not sure is the right way to do so or not. do you have any suggestions for it?

```
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA"),
region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[44.76385083079123, 38.28074335406828],
      [44.76385083079123, 37.1334667575582],
      [46.08221020579123, 37.1334667575582],
      [46.08221020579123, 38.28074335406828]]], null, false),
params = {"opacity":1,"bands":["B4","B3","B2"],"min":0.07630298537191671,"max":0.3954072752450793,"gamma":1.356};

var collection = l8.filterBounds(region)
                    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'LESS_THAN', 30);
                    .filterDate('1999-01-01', '2020-01-01');

var l8med = collection.median();
Map.addLayer(collection, params, 'Layer');

print(collection.size());

var newimg = l8med.visualize(params); 

Export.video.toDrive({
  collection: newimg,
  description: 'a1',
  dimensions: 720,
  framesPerSecond: 12,
  folder: "GEE",
  maxFrames: 100000,
  region: region
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a single image out of the collection using .median() and then tried to export that, so it can't work — there's no time series to make a video out of, after that.

You do need .visualize() but you need to do it for *each* image:

```
Export.video.toDrive({
  collection: collection.map(function (image) { return image.visualize(params); }),
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got this sketchy output: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OhwFslGGviG0TP8_71tcC0d89E_uNe-m